# PHP Rest API Endpoints

Tags: php, rest, api, endpoint

i am making an Rest API and this is my first one.
I am a little bit confused with the endpoints.
[1]http://localhost/01_Diplo/API/API/API/api/participants/
thats what a http request looks right now. This will return a list of all participants from a table.
[2]http://localhost/01_Diplo/API/API/API/api/participants?kz=14escs37
this would get me one specific participant with the "kz" = 14escs37.
participants is just a folder with a index.php inside and i simple check for get request and get value.

Is this how it should look like because some others would make it like this:
[3]http://localhost/01_Diplo/API/API/API/api/participants/14escs37
to get on specific user.

I wonder how i can implement this because when i enter this[3] in my url it expects 14escs37 to be a folder but i want it as an endpoint.

How can i program this into my index.php?

Thanks in advance
Simon

Comment: `urlrewriting` is a keyword for you.

Comment: look into the concepts of a router! This can be done via php only, or with htaccess rewrites.

Comment: Thank you it worker. Just one more question: What does "[0-9]+" mean?
RewriteRule ^teilnehmer/([0-9]+) api/teilnehmer/index.php?kz=$1

Comment: `[0-9]+` matches any number, if there's at least 1.